# Aligning listview under textview

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview

So I am trying to align my listviews under my textview headers. However, everything I have changed from changing the layouts or gravity or anything like that seems to now put the listviews directly under their respective header.
Here is what it looks like right now:
[image]

Here is the XML that has the headers

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--Header aligned to top -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#FC9">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Drive_Number"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Drive_Distance"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Drive_Time"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:background="#005"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:id="@+id/scrollableContents">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the XML that has the listviews:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#CCCCCC"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/Drive_Number_List"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#CCCCCC"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/Drive_Distance_List"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#CCCCCC"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/Drive_Time_List"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems there are two ways you can achieve the "alignment" that you want.

1. **Align the headers as per the `listview` items as shown in picture:**
   Use `LinearLayout` for headers. Divide the three `textviews` (in header) equally by using `android:layout_weight = 1` and `android:layout_width="0dp"` for all, and set `gravity="left"` for the leftmost `textview`, `gravity="right"` for rightmost `textview` and `gravity="center_horizontal"` for middle one.
2. **Keep everything center aligned in its own one-third of total screen width:**
   Use `LinearLayout` for headers as well as listview items. Divide using layout weights and `0dp` width as above. Use `gravity="center_horizontal"` for all items

**Note**: use the "`gravity`" attribute, not "`layout_gravity`"

Comment: For #2 am I just adding that to what I already have? Or am I getting rid of something and adding that in? Because currently everything is pushed to the left side.

Comment: I have tried taking out the `layout_alignParenTop` and the others similar to that in the first listview item and it is still all the way pushed to the left.

Comment: For #2, you should replace the container `RelativeLayout`s with `LinearLayout` for both headers and the listview xml. `layout_alignParentTop` has no significance for `LinearLayout` child views.

Comment: I did that but it pushes drive time off the screen and I have a s7 edge

Comment: Did you also use `layout_weight = 1` for all views? And use `gravity="center_horizontal"`? This should divide screen width equally (1/3rd) for each textview and align the text inside in the middle of their respective sections. If this doesn't work, please update the question with your current xml.

Comment: So for each TextView do that? I'll double check.

Comment: Yes, for each `textview`. And as far as the curved screen of s7 edge is concerned, it should not be a problem with `gravity="center_horizontal"`. Still, if you think the text is getting uncomfortably close to the edge, add some left and right padding to the `Linearlayout`s.

Comment: Ok well then I can't do #1 because those gravity=right will push the right header off the screen and adding paddingEnd doesn't really solve the issue.

Comment: So, did using option #2 with the above clarifications solve the issue? If yes, you can accept this as an answer.

Comment: I have updated the XML files, the headers don't seem to be positioned correctly. And I have tried the padding before with little success but maybe I was doing it wrong?

Comment: You also need to set `android:layout_width="0dp"` for each `textview` otherwise layout_weight won't work correctly. I've tried your xml with this modification and it aligns perfectly. If this still doesn't get what you want, please post the new screenshot of the screen with this layout.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Mind updating your answer so other don't have to go through the comments and I will accept your answer.

Comment: Done. Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can change the padding if you want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!--Header aligned to top -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:background="#FC9"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Drive_Number"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#000"/>
    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Drive_Distance"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Drive_Number"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#000"/>
    <TextView
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Drive_Time"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Drive_Distance"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#000"/>
</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:background="#005"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:id="@+id/scrollableContents">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```